# Swift 5 - Segue between a View controller button to a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The root view controller has a button on it, this button segues to the Navigation View Controller which automatically segues to a Table View. When i set this segue to show(push) it comes up from the bottom and not pushes from the right. I have tried using performSegue instead of doing it in storyboard but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rootViewController` should be `UINavigationController` to show Navigation View Controller which automatically segues to a Table View from right to left ... so make your root view controller a navigation controller

```
NavigationController -> rootController -> segue push-> NavigationController -> TableviewController
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly! Just needed to add some code to hide the bar on the first screen which wasn't too bad.